# Contents of title field "all lowercase" for BibTeX entry?

Tags: natbib

Online resources like this:

```
@MISC{Google:AppEngine:Datastore:Java:API,
  author = {Google},
  year = {2012},
  month = "April",
  title = {Google App Engine Datastore Java API},
  url = "https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/",
  note = "[Accessed: June 2012]"
}
```

have an "all lowercase" title in my bibliography. Non-@MISC resources display just fine.

Example: (the above is displayed as follows)

Google (2012), `Google app engine datastore java api'. [Accessed: June 2012].
URL: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/

I am using:

```
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{multibib}
\bibliographystylereferencedonline{agsm}
\bibliographyreferencedonline{robottinosino}
```

and quoting without citation:

```
\nocitereferencedonline{Google:AppEngine:Datastore:Java:API}
```

Any ideas as to why?

Also, could I have the [Accessed: Month Year] block appear after the nicely formatted URL?

Comment: It is the standard way BibTeX works. If you want uppercase letters in the title just write: `title = {{G}oogle {A}pp {E}ngine {D}atastore {J}ava {API}}`. To change the appearance of the accessed block you need to change the style of bibliography.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You pose two questions. First, to keep the words in the title field -- other than the first one, viz., "Google" --  from becoming set in all-lowercase, encase the publication's title in a second pair of curly braces. I.e., set up the field as

```
title = {{Google App Engine Datastore Java API}},
```

The second question is about how to change the ordering of the output of the fields `url` and `note`, given that you're using the `agsm` bibliography style. The problem with this request is that the ordering of fields of various entry types (`article`, `book`, `techreport`, ...) is currently consistent across all of these entry types in the `agsm` style. It might look downright weird to your readers if the ordering were changed for some entry types only. I would therefore advise *against* fiddling with the ordering of the fields in the function `misc` of the file `agsm.bst`. If you do decide to edit that file, be sure to save it under a new name (say, `myagsm.bst`) rather than overwriting the existing file.

Comment: Answer 1) -> GOLDEN PERFECTION. You are awesome, man. I am becoming a fan. Answer 2) -> Alright, the problem with "plainnat" is that urls look really ugly in it. Do you have a better .bst to use with 'natbib'?

Comment: @Robottinosino -- I'm blushing... About the bibliography style: I thought you were using `agsm`, but now you're suggesting that it's `plainnat`. May I suggest that you post a new question to this group, in which you describe in detail how you would like to see the URLs typeset? (Labeling an existing URL typesetting style "really ugly" does not provide much to go on...)

Comment: Sure, I will post another question. I _am_ using agsm, I was only saying "I am using agsm because I dislike URL handling in plainnat"..

Comment: Hint for Citavi users: Citavi offers an option when exporting to bibtex to add the double-curly-braces.